# Isotope sortByValue

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to sort my products, But this seems not to work, I've got no error's.. What I'm trying to do is sort products with "name" and "fname"

```
<div class="w-filters">
<div class="w-filters-item active" data-sort-by="*">All</div>
<div class="w-filters-item" data-sort-by=".name">Name</div>
<div class="w-filters-item" data-sort-by=".fname">FolderName</div>
</div>
```

with this jQuery

```
jQuery('.w-portfolio.type_sortable').each(function(index, container){
    var $container = jQuery(container),
        $list = $container.find('.w-portfolio-list'),
        $sortItems = $container.find('.w-filters-item');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $list.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.w-portfolio-item',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            getSortData: {
                name: '.name',
                fname: '.fname',
            }
        });
        $sortItems.click(function(){
                var $item =  $item.attr('data-sort-by');
                if ($item.hasClass('active')) return;
                $sortItems.removeClass('active');
                $item.addClass('active');
                $list.isotope({ 
                    sortBy: sortByValue
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Some one who know to fix this?

Comment: Need to see the html of your $container. To sort by name, your itemSelector  would need to have a class of 'name'

Comment: @Macsupport Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L5hdjgz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your fiddle. You can add your libraries like isotope  under "External resources", not in the javascript pane since it is hard to see your code. Also, imagesLoaded.js is not part of isotope v2 ( it was in v1.56) so you need to include that as well. Also, there is no sort "All", that is for filtering so I added original-order instead. 
I did a bit of rewrite on your code. 
Here is the working  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71gpb92z/)

```
  jQuery('.w-portfolio.type_sortable').each(function(){
  var $list = jQuery('.w-portfolio-list'),
    $sortItems = jQuery('.w-filter');
    $list.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $list.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.w-portfolio-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        getSortData: {
            name: '.name',
            fname: '.fname'
        }
    });
    $sortItems.on('click','div',function(){
        var sortByValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-sort-by');
$list.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });               
        });
   });

 $sortItems.each( function( i, sortGroup ) {
var $sortGroup = jQuery( sortGroup );
$sortGroup.on( 'click', 'div', function() {
  $sortGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
  jQuery( this ).addClass('active');
});
});
});
```

Comment: Oh! I see! Thanks man! It's work greate at the jsfiddle, but when I put it inside my file "plugin.js" it's says that "var $sortGroup = $( sortGroup );" is an error. What's it's wrong do you think? @Macsupport

Comment: The error is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" @Macsupport

Comment: I forgot to change '$' to 'jQuery' in part of the code. Updated now

Comment: Thanks @Macsupport ;) yes, You forget to change '$' to 'jQuery( this) ' too ;)

Comment: Updated the code. Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks!